# Icon and Text not centered

Tags: html, css

I have the problem that the logout symbol is placed slightly higher than `Logout`.

I tried adding margin to make the icon the same height and in the same row as the text, but that doesn't seem to work.

```css
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
        padding: 14px;
        background-color: yellow;
}

#logout-icon {
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <img id="logout-icon" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2518/PNG/512/logout_icon_151219.png">
        <span>Logout</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy fix is to use FlexBox for `.dropdown-content`.

Here is an example:

```css
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 14px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take advantage of the flex property for something like this. Adjust the gap property until you are okay with the spacing.

```css
.dropdown-content {
    display: inline-flex;
    gap: 0.5rem;

    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;

}

#logout-icon {
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <img id="logout-icon" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2518/PNG/512/logout_icon_151219.png">
        <span>Logout</span>
    </div>
</div>
```